# ngIf for different type of key from Javascript Array

Tags: arrays, typescript, angular6, javascript-objects

```
concerts: [
    {
        key: "field_concerts_time",
        lbl: "Date"
    }, {
        key: ["field_concert_fromtime", "field_concert_totime"],
        lbl: "Time",
        concat: "to"
    }, {
        key: "field_concerts_agereq",
        lbl: "Age Requirements"
    }, {
        key: "field_concerts_dresscode",
        lbl: "Dress Code"
    }, {
        key: "field_concerts_prices",
        lbl: "Prices"
    }

]

 descriptions: {

 "field_concerts_time": [

  {
  "value": "2019-09-16T00:00:00",
  }
  ],

"field_concert_totime": [

  {
  "value": "1:00AM"
  }

  ],

 "field_concert_fromtime": [

  {
  "value": "7:30PM"
  }

  ]
  }
```

I have concerts array and descriptions object i want to take the "key" from the concerts and take value for that field

```
    <p *ngFor="let otherdetail of otherdetailsarray">
    <span *ngIf="descriptions[otherdetail.key][0].value !== null"> 
      {{otherdetail.lbl}} :</span>
    <span *ngIf="descriptions[otherdetail.key][0].value !== null && 
      descriptions[otherdetail.key][0].value !== undefined"> 
      {{descriptions[otherdetail.key][0].value }}</span>
  </p>
```

I got the value for the 1'st index's key "field_concerts_time" and took value from description using above tags. I want this code to support `"key: ["field_concert_fromtime", "field_concert_totime"]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Check whether you've reached the concert's Time-object.
If so, handle the key as an array by indexing fields 0 and 1 additionally.

```
<p *ngFor="let otherdetail of otherdetailsarray">
<span *ngIf="descriptions[otherdetail.key][0].value !== null"> 
  {{otherdetail.lbl}} :</span>

<span *ngIf="otherdetail.lbl !== 'Time' &&
  descriptions[otherdetail.key][0].value !== null && 
  descriptions[otherdetail.key][0].value !== undefined">
  {{descriptions[otherdetail.key][0].value }} 
</span>

<span *ngIf="otherdetail.lbl == 'Time' &&
  descriptions[otherdetail.key[0]][0].value && 
  descriptions[otherdetail.key[1]][0].value"> 
   {{descriptions[otherdetail.key[0]][0].value }} {{otherdetail.concat}}
  {{descriptions[otherdetail.key[1]][0].value }}
  </span>

</p>
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, I had to correct my code once again as there was a typo. Should work now.